# Can I throttle exception emails from log4j?

Tags: logging, error-handling, log4j, error-logging

I have a java process (inside tomcat) that uses log4j to log to files and send mails for exceptions. This works very well until the other day a piece of code got caught in a bad way, throwing many exceptions every few seconds - sending several thousand emails.

Is there any way to throttle emails sent from log4j? Maybe "only send this exception once" or "send this exception a maximum of once every 5 minutes".

(Of course I'll fix the code for this specific circumstance, but it runs every 10s overnight, so in future, a similar thing may happen)

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: You might want to try this one:
https://github.com/reaktor/log4j-email-throttle Simple, but works.